# Flutter in_app_purchase: ^3.0.6 not list subscriptions

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

i'm using in_app_purchase: ^3.0.6 flutter plugin to integrate the in app purchases
the example loads correctly my consumable products with the available value button to make the purchase, but the subscriptions items return an "not found error"

```
const bool _kAutoConsume = true;
const String _kConsumableId = 'ca001';
const String _kConsumableId2 = 'ca002';
const String _kConsumableId3 = 'ca003';
const String _kUpgradeId = null;
const String _kSilverSubscriptionId ="ca004";
const String _kGoldSubscriptionId = null;
const List<String> _kProductIds = <String>[
  _kConsumableId,
  _kConsumableId2,
  _kConsumableId3,
  _kSilverSubscriptionId,
];
```

the first 3 items loads and show correctly, but the subscription code "ca004" shows not found,
the subscription code appear active in play store.

[image]

[image]

where is the issue to get the subscription items available to purchase?

Comment: +10. hi! did you find any solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: Since one-time purchases work for you, I assume you've set up your permissions, your device and your Google Play Console settings correctly, so the error likely lies in your implementation. How are you loading your IAPs (both one-time purchases and subscriptions)? Do you know where exactly the error occurs and do you have any error logs? Please include more code snippets.